# Trouble dynamically creating a custom lightning component (non aura component)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I'm trying to dynamically create a custom component and insert it into the body of another one. That component (CaseComponent) has a Case attribute. The trouble is that the Case attribute is never filled, and I get an error when I try to reference the Case's fields, such as the CaseNumber.

Here is the Case Component:

```
<aura:component>
<aura:attribute type="Case" name="case"/>
<div class="case">
    <p class="textCenter caseNumber">{!case.CaseNumber}</p>
    <p>Status: {!case.Status}</p>
    <p>Subject: {!case.Subject}</p>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript controller that tries to make this component dynamically.

```
$A.createComponent(
"c:CaseComponent",
{
    "case": testCase,
},
function(newCaseList){
    if (component.isValid()) {
        var body = component.get("v.body");
        body.push(newCaseList);
        component.set("v.body", body);
    }
});
```

I'm getting the following error message

> "Assertion Failed!: Unable to get value for key 'case.CaseNumber'. No
>   value provider was found for 'case'. : false. Please try again."

If anyone has any idea as to what I could be doing wrong for this not to work, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your logic is right, but your syntax is incorrect. Try changing `{!case.CaseNumber}` to `{!v.case.CaseNumber}` and do the same for the others.